Type annotations: pathlib.Path vs importlib.resources.abc.Traversable
When loading file resources that are bundled inside my distribution package, I use importlib.resources.files. When loading files from disk, I use pathlib.Path.
Sometimes I want to write a function that will take either:
from importlib.resources.abc import Traversable
from pathlib import Path

def process_file(file_to_process: Traversable | Path) -> None: ...

It feels cumbersome to annotate all file-processing functions with Traversable | Path. I could define and use my own union type, but that feels like something that Python might already have built-in that I'm missing. I only require the basic subset of both types: open / close / read / write, etc, and nothing like touching permissions or using OS-specific details.
What is the correct type to use for a file resource that can be loaded from a distribution package via importlib or from a drive via pathlib?
I'm currently using Python 3.11 but will upgrade over time, so all 3.11+ answers are welcome.

What sort of resources are you trying to support? Do you want to support arbitrary resources, or just "ordinary files"? If you're just using "ordinary files", do note that the Traversable that importlib.resources.files returns will be a bona fide Path instance.

This is thankfully very simple, I'm just using basic file io- in this case I'm often only just reading the entire contents of small text files. I had previously been using typing.cast(pathlib.Path, ...) on the result of importlib.resources.files to placate pyright, but that felt wrong because the underlying backing type being pathlib.Path doesn't appear to be part of the importlib API. What if it changes, etc.

To convert a Traversable into a Path one can use importlib.resources.as_file(traversable), see https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.resources.html#importlib.resources.as_file

I believe you can just use Traversable in all cases. It looks like Traversable is a protocol, and since pathlib.Path implements the necessary methods, objects of type pathlib.Path should also be Traversable. And in fact:
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> from importlib.resources.abc import Traversable
>>> p = Path('.')
>>> isinstance(p, Path)
True
>>> isinstance(p, Traversable)
True

So you should be able to write:
def process_file(file_to_process: Traversable) -> None: ...


I've checked, and mypy seems happy with the above annotation when calling process_file(Path('example.txt')).

Thanks! Coming from importlib.resources makes Traversable look strange to my eye in locations where I'm only doing filesystem work- I'd probably use pathlib.Path for those types, but it makes sense to use Traversable for any parts of the code that could operate on both.
